# How to access a variable in a function of a module?

Tags: python, global-variables, python-module

I have a variable in my main code and I have a function in a module made to change such variable. I don't know how to access such variable from an outside function.

```
# MyModule

def func(x):
  x = x + 2
```

And I wanto to do:

```
# Main code
import MyModule
a = 10
MyModule.func(a)
# Expected a = 12
```

Comment: Parameters are passed by value, not by reference. The variable `x` is unrelated to `a`, they both just hold the value.

Comment: Can't you add a `return` to `func` and do `a = MyModule.func(a)`? This looks like a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), maybe if we were to have more details on what the actual function is supposed to do...

Comment: Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: I returned the variables I nedded to, The code I was trying to make was a function that takes two lists (X,Y), then returned the coefficients of a linear regression function, the error of it, the sum of the errors squared and the correlation coefficient. As I need to use it for multiple sets of data I was planning to name those variables the same through all my code and just change their values by calling the function.